# How to split an array by the length of the elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string-length

I have an array with string elements of different lengths. I need to split this array in several arrays, each one containing the strings of just one specific length.

Example:

```
$allstrings = ('hello', 'world', 'stackoverflow');
```

I need:

```
$length4 = ('hello', 'world');
$length12 = ('stackoverflow');
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Apart from the fact "hello" and "world" are 5, and "stackoverflow" is 13, you can foreach, and use `strlen($str)`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fact "hello" and "world" are 5, and "stackoverflow" is 13, you can foreach, and use `strlen($str)`

```
$allstrings = array('hello', 'world', 'stackoverflow');
```

I would suggest using a Multidimensional Array:

```
$array = array();
foreach($allstrings as $str) {
  $array[strlen($str)][] = $str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this *specific* example, you want to create arrays containing strings that match a certain length, and assign those arrays to variables with the following naming convention: `$lengthN` where N is the strings length minus one.

Here's how you can use that using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
foreach($allstrings as $string) {
    // Remove one as per your spec
    $len = strlen($string) - 1;
    // Set temp var name
    $var_name = 'length' . $len;
    // Initialize variable variable
    if(!isset(${$var_name}))
        ${$var_name} = array();

    // Add variable variable's new array entry 
    ${$var_name}[] = $string;
}

print_r($length4);
print_r($length12);
```

[Output:](https://eval.in/194323)

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => world
)
Array
(
    [0] => stackoverflow
)
```

Despite this producing your required result, you should consider the fact that creating arbitrary variable names is not a good idea. Containing them within arrays is a structured solution that gives you the bounds to access them without knowing what they are represented by. In this case, you **need** to know to use `$length4` or `$length12`. Food for thought.